# React component missing elements of props

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am trying to add a smart component to my application, and typescript continuously yells at me for not adding enough props. Below is the code I am trying to add: I started off from the asp.net core spa application with react redux and have been trying to build from there.

```
<Layout>
    <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
    <Route path='/counter' component={ Counter } />
    <Route path='/fetchdata/:startDateIndex?' component={ FetchData } />
</Layout>;

type LayoutProps = LayoutState.LayoutState
    & typeof LayoutState.actionCreators;


class Layout extends React.Component<LayoutProps, {}> {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.requestNavigationLinks();
    }

    public render() {
        return <Grid fluid>
            <Row>
                <Col sm={3}>
                    <NavMenu links={this.props.links}/>
                </Col>
                <Col sm={9}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Grid>;
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.layout,
    LayoutState.actionCreators
)(Layout) as typeof Layout;

export interface LayoutState {
    isLoading: boolean;
    links: string[];
}
```

The issue that I am having is that the typescript is complaining that the  tag is missing properties being assigned to its props. Does the connect statement not automatically handle this?

I am sure this is something easy I am missing and your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the export line. I took it from the aspnet-spa example:

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.layout,
    LayoutState.actionCreators
)(Layout) as typeof Layout;
```

Because of the `as typeof Layout;` verbiage, the component is expecting me to pass in all of those variables explicitly. Removing it solved my problem.

Comment: Having had the same problem with TypeScript complaining about not having props on state / action creators, I compared to the above. I didn't have the typeof, but the problem was that state didn't have a type (which weirdly, Typescript was not complaining about despite `noImplicitAny` compiler option), but adding the type, e.g. in your example `ApplicationState` fixed this issue for me. TypeScript now compiles, although WebStorm still complains about the missing props, even after restart.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `requestNavigationLinks` is a defined property in the LayoutState.  You could try to add it to the interface.

For example:

```
export interface LayoutState {
    isLoading: boolean;
    links: string[];
    requestNavigationLinks: func;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't include the definition of LayoutProps, it is almost exactly like you have just with types of the function. It is actually complaining about the isLoading is missing, if I add that then it complains about links and finally requestNavigationLinks.

Comment: No worries.  I found a useful article that may help you: http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/. Read the "Connect" section.  It may unearth the missing piece to your problem.